# Webpack is returning '__dirname' as '/'

Tags: webpack, swagger, nestjs, angular-universal

When I try to compile the Angular 8 app with Nestjs backend webpack seems to have issues with it and returns `__dirname` as "/"

I tried using suggestions from other topics to set in the config __dirname: true or false and it seems that API is not accepting this config.

Below I'm pasting the default config with the factory and the error that I'm getting

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackConfigFactory = require('@nestjs/ng-universal')
  .WebpackConfigFactory;

module.exports = WebpackConfigFactory.create(webpack, {
  // Nest server for SSR
  server: './server/main.ts'
});
```

When trying to compile using 'npm run serve:ssr' after successful build i get this:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//indexTemplate.html.tpl' ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//indexTemplate.html.tpl' at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3) at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35) at Object.generateHTML (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:80659:16) at Function.setupExpress (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:79512:39) at Function.setup (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:79505:21) at C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:129:33 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at fulfilled (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:95:58) at Zone.run (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:1633:43) errno: -4058, syscall: 'open', code: 'ENOENT', path: '//indexTemplate.html.tpl' } Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//indexTemplate.html.tpl' at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3) at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35) at Object.generateHTML (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:80659:16) at Function.setupExpress (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:79512:39) at Function.setup (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:79505:21) at C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:129:33 at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at fulfilled (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:95:58) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:1874:26) at Zone.run (C:\Users\Work\PhpstormProjects\terminal-app\dist\server.js:1633:43)
```

I already filed this as a bug in nestjs/swagger repo, as this is happening mostly with swagger from what I see. Didn't notice the bug on pure Angular 8+. 
Nevertheless, any clue if there is any workaround for it?

Answer (score 3):

Webpack by default [mocking](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__filename) the `__dirname` variable to `/`.

You can change it by disabling this feature.

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...

  node: {
    '__dirname': false
  }
}
```

Comment: Yah I tried it, but it works on pure angular or pure nestjs but when integrating them with @nestjs/ng-universal it throws me this on build:

Comment: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.

Comment: Details:
    * configuration.entry['node'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['node'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['node'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['node'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name

Comment: Sounds like one of those deps are consuming an old webpack version.
Try to check via `npm ls webpack`

Comment: The output is: 
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.801.3
  `-- webpack@4.35.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your webpack.config.js

```
node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true, <-- in case of need
},
```